# The cost function in logistic regression is giving nan values

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am implementing logistic regression with gradient descent from scratch in python. I am working on [breast cancer dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/merishnasuwal/breast-cancer-prediction-dataset). While calculating the cost, I am getting only nan values. I tried to standardize my data and tried decreasing my alpha value but it had no effect. Despite this I am getting a 95.8% accuracy. Something feels wrong. Given below is some of my code:

```
def hypothesis(b,X):
    z= np.dot(X,b)
    #print(z)
    return sigmoid(z)

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-1*z))

def FindCost(h,y):
    r = y.shape[0]
    cost = np.sum(y*np.log(h)+(1-y)*np.log(1-h))/r
    #print(cost)
    return cost*-1
    
def gradient_descent(X,y,alpha,epoch):
    r = X.shape[0]
    c = X.shape[1]
    theta = np.ones((c,1))
    min_cost=None
    min_theta=[]
    Cost_list=[]
    for i in range(epoch):
        h = hypothesis(theta,X)
        grad = np.dot(X.T,(h-y))
        theta = theta - alpha*grad
        cost = FindCost(h,y)
        Cost_list.append(cost)
        if min_cost is None or min_cost>cost:
            min_cost=cost
            min_theta=list(theta)
    return min_theta,Cost_list   

def calAccuracy(theta,X,y):
    h = hypothesis(theta,X)
    correct=0
    for i in range(y.shape[0]):
        if h[i]>=0.5:
            if y[i]==1: correct+=1
            print("predicted: ",1,end='\t\t')
        elif h[i]<0.5:
            if y[i]==0: correct+=1
            print("predicted: ",0,end='\t\t')
        print("actual: ",y[i])
    return correct*100/y.shape[0]


alpha = 0.01
epoch = 1000
theta,cost = gradient_descent(x_train,y_train,alpha,epoch)
accuracy = calAccuracy(theta,x_test,y_test)
print(f"the accuracy of the model: {accuracy} %")

Output:
the accuracy of the model: 95.8041958041958 %
```

standardization of dataset:

```
for i in range(x_train.shape[1]):
    x_train[i] = (x_train[i]-np.mean(x_train[i]))/np.std(x_train[i])
    x_test[i] = (x_test[i]-np.mean(x_test[i]))/np.std(x_test[i])
```

Dataset looks like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5uxZ.png)

I concatenate a column of ones (first column) to my x_train and x_test after I standardized my dataset.

```
x train data:
 [[ 1.00000000e+00 -6.51198873e-01 -5.29762615e-01  4.19236602e-02
   1.91948751e+00 -7.80449683e-01]
 [ 1.00000000e+00 -6.85821055e-01 -4.00751146e-01 -3.29500919e-02
   1.92747771e+00 -8.07955419e-01]
 [ 1.00000000e+00 -6.76114725e-01 -4.04963490e-01 -6.16161982e-02
   1.93556890e+00 -7.92874483e-01]

y train data:
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
    
x test data:
 [[ 1.00000000e+00 -5.63066669e-01 -5.36144255e-01 -2.71074811e-01
   1.98575469e+00 -6.15468953e-01]
 [ 1.00000000e+00 -5.57037602e-01 -5.57366708e-01 -2.60414280e-01
   1.98474749e+00 -6.09928901e-01]
 [ 1.00000000e+00 -5.56192661e-01 -5.57892986e-01 -2.62657675e-01
   1.98504143e+00 -6.08298112e-01]

y test data:
 [[0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
```

What am I doing wrong here and how to prevent nan values from showing up?
Also, if my cost function is giving me nan values, how am I getting so much accuracy?

P.S. I had no null values in my dataset initially and converted the dataset into numpy array.

Comment: The page you've linked to requires authentication. It would be nice to provide some example values from `x_train` and `y_train`, what do they look like I can see that they are `np.array` instances, but what is their shape?

Comment: I have added an image of the dataset.

Comment: I meant **TEXT** data that we can work with. I can generate an arrray like this `x_train = np.array([x for x in range(100)])` but I can't be sure that it will be the same with your data. Please provide something we can use like a few examples of your dataset as an `np.array`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a look at the guidelines for asking a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your questions needs to be reproducible as @Countour-Integral explains.

Comment: the code and data you provided do not produce nans in variable cost.

Comment: Try using np.dot() function.

Comment: I tested my code and it still shows nan values

Comment: np.dot() on cost still giving me nan values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was:

```
for i in range(x_train.shape[1]):
    x_train[i] = (x_train[i]-np.mean(x_train[i]))/np.std(x_train[i])
    x_test[i] = (x_test[i]-np.mean(x_test[i]))/np.std(x_test[i])
```

The standardization was not done Feature-Wise / Column Wise.
You should use this instead:

```
for i in range(x_train.shape[1]):
    x_train[:,i] = (x_train[:,i]-np.mean(x_train,axis=1))/np.std(x_train,axis=1)
    x_test[:,i] = (x_test[:,i]-np.mean(x_test,axis=1))/np.std(x_test,axis=1)
```

This will give correct values of cost with Accuracy: 95.8041958041958 %